# Checking for equilibrium in a square configuration of charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, equilibrium

Four equal positive charges each of magnitude q are placed at the respective vertices of a square of side length l. A point Q is placed at the centre of the square. Then find the state of equilibrium of charge Q (stable, unstable or neutral)

I figured that the charge Q was in equilibrium because the force on it was zero but couldn't find out if it were stable or not. I know that in stable equilibrium, a small displacement results in SHM about the mean position so I tried to write an equation of force for a small displacement but couldn't succeed in formulating the equation. Any help regarding writing the force on a small displacement would be deeply appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: A general hint without calculating anything: look at the properties of [harmonic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function); especially the maximum principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example, the case when the charge Q at the centre is negative, so the force is attractive.

If it gets displaced even by a small  value $\delta r$ towards either, the separation with this particular vertex would be $(\frac{l}{\sqrt 2}-\delta r)$, while it is slightly larger for the others. Due to the inverse dependence of the force on this separation squared, the attractive force towards this vertex would be larger than towards the other three. The condition of zero net force is no longer satisfied, and the direction of net force is towards this vertex. So, this charge will continuously keep moving towards it, under it reaches the vertex (and annihilates). Clearly, there is no restoration here, so the equilibrium is unstable.

---

Edit - As prompted by the OP, I am feeding in more details.

The situation is represented by the following diagram:

[image: Net force calculation]

Charges q each are on the vertices, and Q is at the point O originally. As long as it stays at this point, the net force on it is zero, since forces due to the four vertices cancel out. We have to see what happens if it gets displaced along one of the sides, say towards A. Say, it got displaced infinitesimally, by a small amount $\delta r$ towards A. This $\delta r$ subtends an angle $\theta$ at the vertices B and D, such that 
$$\tan \theta = \frac{\delta r}{(l/\sqrt{2})} = \frac{\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l}$$

For convenience, let us adopt "natural units" here, so that Q = q = 1, and $\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} = 1$. (This is just for convenience, if you don't like this system of units, simply multiply each of the following terms by the factor $\frac{Qq}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}$. Since this part is common for all all four, it doesn't matter - you can even multiply the final answer by this factor directly.)

Electrostatic force is $\propto \frac{1}{r^2}$ is all we need for this.

Distance to the vertex A  $= (\frac{l}{\sqrt 2} - \delta r)$

Distance to the vertex B  $= (\frac{l}{\sqrt 2} + \delta r)$

Clearly therefore, ${\vec F}_{\rm towards \ A} \ne {\vec F}_{\rm towards \ B}$, the former being larger due to the smaller denominator. These two don't cancel out, and the net force is directed towards A.

In comparison, if we take into account the vertices C and D,

Distance to the vertex C  $= \sqrt{(\frac{l}{\sqrt 2})^2 + (\delta r)^2}$ = Distance to the vertex D

But while distances are equal, these forces are not antiparallel, and hence, won't cancel out completely.

Let us resolve these into components along the axis AB and transverse to it. For example, the force ${\vec F}_{\rm towards \ C}$ has a transverse component $\big\vert {\vec F}_{\rm towards \ C} \big\vert \cos \theta$, while the component along AB is $\big\vert {\vec F}_{\rm towards \ C} \big\vert \sin \theta$.

Two deductions here:

For small angles, $\cos \theta$ is much bigger than $\sin \theta$, so the dominant contribution is the transverse component which cancelled out. So, the component along the axis AB is the smaller component. Secondly, for small angles $\sin \theta \approx \tan \theta$, (both being approximately equal to $\theta$, but I'll not use this. I'll only use $\sin \theta \approx \tan \theta$).

So, the $\cos \theta$ components cancel out, while the $\sin \theta$ components add up. As can be seen from the figure, these will be directed towards B, and this extra contribution has strength:

$$2 \big\vert {\vec F}_{\rm towards \ C} \big\vert \sin \theta \approx 2 \big\vert {\vec F}_{\rm towards \ C} \big\vert \tan \theta, $$

which comes out to be (upon plugging in)

$$\frac{2}{(\frac{l}{\sqrt 2})^2 + (\delta r)^2} \times \frac{\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l}$$

which could be rewritten as

$$\frac{2 \sqrt{2}\delta r}{\frac{l^3}{2}(1 + (\frac{\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l})^2)} = \frac{4 \sqrt{2}\delta r}{l^3(1 + (\frac{2(\delta r)^2}{l^2}))}$$

Since the last factor is small, it can be treated using the binomial theorem, $(1+x)^{-1} \approx (1-x)$.

This reduces the above factor to 
$$\frac{4 \sqrt{2}\delta r}{l^3} (1 - (\frac{2(\delta r)^2}{l^2})) \approx \frac{4 \sqrt{2}\delta r}{l^3} $$

since the other term is of the order of $(\delta r)^3/l^5$ and hence, is very very small. This is the extra component aimed towards B.

Now, we have to find the net difference between the force along A and total force along B. For evaluating these, one would need the value of separation squared for both of these cases (in terms of such binomial expansions). Let us do these first.

$$\frac{1}{(\frac{l}{\sqrt 2} - \delta r)^2} = \frac{2}{l^2} (1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l})^{-2} \approx \frac{2}{l^2} (1 + \frac{2\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l})$$

and by the same token

$$ \frac{1}{(\frac{l}{\sqrt 2} + \delta r)^2} \approx \frac{2}{l^2} (1 - \frac{2\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l}) $$

So, we have

$$\big\vert {\vec F}_{\rm towards \ A}\big\vert - \big\vert{\vec F}_{\rm towards \ B} \big\vert = \Big[ \frac{2}{l^2} (1 + \frac{2\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l})\Big] - \Big[ \frac{2}{l^2} (1 - \frac{2\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l}) + \frac{4\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l^3} \Big]$$

which yields on simplifying,

$$ \big\vert {\vec F}_{\rm towards \ A}\big\vert - \big\vert{\vec F}_{\rm towards \ B} \big\vert = \frac{4\sqrt{2}\delta r}{l^3}$$

Thus,

$$ \big\vert {\vec F}_{\rm towards \ A}\big\vert > \big\vert{\vec F}_{\rm towards \ B} \big\vert$$

and the resultant force is aimed towards A, which goes in support of my claim of the absence of any restoring force. Hence, the equilibrium is unstable.

Comment: The argument is very much the same if Q is negative, except that the slightly larger force will be repulsive.

Comment: @mmesser314 - Yes, but in this case, you get an aesthetic simplicity, the test charge keeps moving towards that vertex where it had got displaced by a mere amount. I only eased by taking this example. I buy your point though :)

Comment: @TheDarkSide The answer might be correct but operated on assumptions. You have not taken the component of forces due to the other vertices(vertices perpendicular to direction of the small distance moved) which is against the direction of the force where the distance is (l/(root 2)−δr). (those two forces are not exactly balances since the charges are no longer in equilibrium).

Comment: @thewinnerishere - If you resolve into components along "my direction of motion" and transverse to it, you will find that these transverse components for the pair would cancel out, while the 'along' ones add up. I don't think that will make any difference, but let me think more carefully here.

Comment: @TheDarkSide you are right, the ones which are transverse cancel out but the contribution of the components(which don't cancel) is towards charge OPPOSITE to the final direction of displacement. Hence I thought it would be more appropriate to actually write down the forces and then check for the equilibrium.

Comment: @thewinnerishere - I have worked it out. I will update the answer with the details. Please be patient with me, got a lot of typing to do here :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the square to be in the x-y plane. Then see what happens when you displace the central charge in the z-direction.

Of course, the answer will depend upon whether Q is positive or negative and possibly also on the direction of displacement.